# How do I pass a variable from server side to client side js Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im using an external API. I'd like to show logged in user's nickname (steam API)

server main.js

```
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
      { service: 'steam' },
      {
        $set: {
          loginStyle: 'redirect',
          timeout: 10000 // 10 seconds
        }
      }
    );

    Accounts.onLogin(function() {
        var steam64Id = Meteor.user().profile.id;
        console.log(steam64Id + " is logged in.");

        // To retrieve more details about user

        var steamApiKey = ("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            var result = Meteor.http.get('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=xxxxxxxxx&steamids=76561197977045111');
                console.log(result.data.response.players[0].personaname);  
    });
  });
```

This returns "My Nickname" in the console log, but I'd like to retrieve this variable in client side so I can add {{Nickname}} to client js template and show user's Nickname in the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious way would be to add that result to the user's profile in their user record. Then it would automatically be synchronized to the client and available for use there.

```
var steamApiKey = ("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
var result = Meteor.http.get('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=xxxxxxxxx&steamids=76561197977045111');
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(),
  { $set: { 'profile.personaname': result.data.response.players[0].personaname }}
);
```

On the client side, make yourself a helper (either a global one or one specific to the template(s) where you need it) to get this value:

```
Nickname(){
  return Meteor.user().profile.personaname;
}
```

Note that the profile object under the user is automatically published to the client so you don't have to make a special publication for it.

Comment: Thanks Michel, really appreciate that. Im wonderin, will the output still be the same if a different user logs in? Its updating the unique userId? At what situation will the userId change but the it is the same user? Because I'd like to create a db for users who logged in before/new users

Comment: I don't see where you're getting a different personaname from the steam API with a different user. Shouldn't some part of the user's profile be part of the http get? It's easy to query people who have or don't have `profile.personaname` set with `$isSet`

Comment: You are right, it differs, but I'm just wonder about this part, Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), if say, I log in to the site from 2 different machines/ISP, will Meteor.userId() be different or same for both? Im just concerned coz I wanna use a db to store any users to logs in to the site, afraid there might be dupes. Then again I can set an if steam64id already exist, i can just update it there.

Comment: Ok upon Accounts.onLogin function, I added a mongodb, PlayersList and under Accounts.onLogin I added PlayersList.Insert the users personaname etc etc.. So I refreshed site a few times and checked db, it created duplicates, all extracted info are the same however, the _id differs. Is there a way I can prevent this?

Comment: If you login from two different machines your `userId()` is always the same. If `personaname` is 1:1 with the user then you might as well put it in the user's profile, no need for another collection.

Comment: you right. lol... i dont know why i wanted to make another collection. is it possible to create dynamic routed templates? e.g. when user clicks {{steamPersonanaName}} it will redirect to, /profile/steam64Id. So e.g. I click on my personaname, it'll redirect to /profile/76561197977045111

Comment: Yes of course, look at FlowRouter or IronRouter. You want a parameterized  route like `/profile/:steam64Id` (note the colon in the route)

Comment: Thank you, it wasnt working before but realized my helpers weren't global. Now works. Is storing db this way secured? I'd like to implement in site sort of credits/currency so it would be devastating if someone could alter it. how do I secure the db and where do I look to ensure proper server/client interaction?